# How can i access remote desktop Xubuntu from Ubuntu14

Tags: xubuntu, rdp

i have server that works on xubuntu. How can i access it from my laptop that runs Ubuntu?

Answer (score 0):

I would use ssh to remote control your server instead of remote desktop.
Install ssh on your server open up a terminal on your server.

```
sudo apt-get install openssh-server
```

on your Ubuntu client open up a terminal and type in.

```
ssh -X 'username'@serverip
```

The -X forwards the x11 request so if you want to open file manager you just type in  `thunar` and it will forward the -X 11 request to your computer and then you will be able to view file and fodders on the server.